# Default "legend" function overwritten by accident

Tags: matlab, path

I am using the BNT-toolbox, a big library written in matlab for inference in bayesian networks.

I had to add this toolbox to the path of MATLAB. But after doing that I can't use the default `legend` function any more.

I think that this library might have his own `legend` function, overwriting the default one. How can I manually tell MATLAB that I want the original one and not the one in the new toolbox?

Tried in Matlab 2018b and 2020a

EDIT: to reproduce it:

When I run the testscript, it shows the lines and the legend.

https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt, this is the toolbox I talked about. I downloaded it, unzipped and then added it to my path with *Home -> Set path -> add folder with subfolder*

When I run the script now, it shows the lines and not the legend.

NOTE: when I tried another way of plotting (see testscript 2), the legend shows itself again. So this is a working "workaround"

Testscript1: (location: C:\Users\TomDe\Downloads\FullBNT-1.0.7\bnt\own\testscript1.m)

```
x = linspace(0,pi);
y1 = cos(x);
plot(x,y1)

hold on 
y2 = cos(2*x);
plot(x,y2)

legend('cos(x)','cos(2x)')
```

Testscript2

```
% Some other code

tiledlayout(2,1) 
nexttile
plot(inputPath)
hold on
plot(sensorPath)
plot(inputInference)
hold off
title('The Input sequence and sensor readings  ')
legend('Path', 'sensor', 'Inference')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check that that is indeed the case with the [which](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function:

```
>> which legend -all
```

It's generally a bad idea to overshadow MATLAB's own functions. I highly suggest you avoid this problem in the first place. Create a [MATLAB package](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html#brf3g8k) and place the source code of this toolbox in there.

---

For demonstration purposes only, I'll show how to call the real `legend.m`:

```
>> wd = pwd;
>> cd 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\toolbox\matlab\scribe\'
>> legend(...)
>> cd(wd);
```

this being the location of the file on a MATLAB R2020a install.

Comment: I was indeed looking for something like this Which. When i run it, it just prints: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\toolbox\matlab\scribe\legend.m (so to do the default one and nothing in the toolbox). Altough, when I run a little script to show the legend it does not appear. Note: by removing the toolbox from the path, and running the same script, the legend DOES appear. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: @TomDeConinck `when I run a little script` what does this script do? Please add it to the question. Also what's the full path of this script?

Comment: @TomDeConinck Can you point me to the source code of this toolbox? If you give me reproduction steps I can try and reproduce this

Comment: @TomDeConinck There is no `legend.m` in that toolbox. Check with `find bnt-master -name "legend.m"`, so it must be something wrong with your code. Are there any warnings or error messages displayed in the command window when you run the code where `legend` does not show?

Comment: Testscript1 runs completly and then shows the figure (with no legend). The command window throws no errors or warnings.

Comment: Adding the following the lines at the start, solves the problem: tiledlayout(2,1) 
nexttile. Can you explain why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. You always want to use the default `legend`, never the one in the toolbox: use [the `-end` option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html#btpdm64-1-position) to your `addpath` call when adding the BNT toolbox directory, so that its functions appear at the end of the path. MATLAB will always find functions by looking through the path directories in turn, the directories earlier in the path therefore have precedence.
2. You want to use both versions of `legend`, and want to choose which one to use: write a little support function that removes the BTN toolbox from your path, calls `legend`, then adds the toolbox back in. Such a function looks like this (save it as `original_legend.m` somewhere in your path, then use it in the same way you'd call `legend` but using this new name instead):

   ```matlab
   function out = original_legend(varargin)
   rmpath /path/to/bnt/toolbox
   out = legend(varargin{:});
   addpath /path/to/bnt/toolbox
   ```